# Cannot add custom Jackson deserializer?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I built custom `java.security.Key` serializers and deserializers for Jackson. They are declare as

```
public class KeySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Key>
```

and

```
public class KeyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Key>
```

When I use the decorators as in:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = KeySerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = KeyDeserializer.class)
private PublicKey publicKey;
```

it works just fine, but I'm trying to use them in a case where the decorators, as far as I know, are not applied ([Hibernate JSON](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/)). In this case, I actually have a class that creates the Object mapper:

```
public class JacksonUtil {
    public static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
}
```

When I use that object mapper, I get the error:

To try to make it work, I registered the (de)serializer like this:

```
No serializer found for class org.bouncycastle.math.ec.WNafL2RMultiplier and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPublicKey["parameters"]->org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec["curve"]->org.bouncycastle.math.ec.custom.sec.SecP521R1Curve["multiplier"])
```

I think it's essentially saying that there are no serializers for BCECPublicKey. So, I add the (de)serializer like this:

```
static {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Key.class, new KeySerializer());
    OBJECT_MAPPER.registerModule(module);
    module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(Key.class, new KeyDeserializer());
    OBJECT_MAPPER.registerModule(module);
}
```

Serialization seems to work, but deserialization doesn't:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPublicKey: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

That error is correct, but that's why I created my own deserializer that knows how to create a BCECPublicKey, but it's not being called.

Any ideas why my custom deserializer is not being called?

I also tried to add it like this:

```
module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(BCECPublicKey.class, new KeyDeserializer());
OBJECT_MAPPER.registerModule(module);
```

but I get the error:

```
Error:(34, 15) java: method addDeserializer in class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Class<T>,com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer<? extends T>
  found: java.lang.Class<org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPublicKey>,tech.dashman.common.crypto.KeyDeserializer
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPublicKey
    lower bounds: java.security.Key
```

`BCECPublicKey` implements `Key` and indeed in my tests this deserializer works. What's going on here?

Comment: Do you need a solution or do you need some jackson internal logic explanations? If you need the solution, i think this should work for you `class KeyDeserializer<T extends Key> extends JsonDeserializer<T>`  cast the return type of deserializer to T `return (T) resultObject` and register it like `module.addDeserializer(BCECPublicKey.class, new KeyDeserializer<>());`

Comment: Nice solution .. thanks a lot :)